# Want to execute all the threads parallelly in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a work flow designed in JMeter, which I want to execute parallelly. Please refer the image attached. One way to do it that I can use distributed load system and execute the same test plan parallelly. But I have only one machine. Currently I am using parallel controller for executing this and I wonder there must be intelligent way of handling this. Any help on such ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your setup is correct, the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) executes its **children in parallel**, it means that

1. "User 1" will be executed first and all these requests like `Retrieve bearer token`, `retrieve country details`, etc. will be executed **at exactly the same moment** so if `retrieve country details` requests needs the token - it will fail
2. "User 2" will be executed **after "User1" completion**

So I would recommend:

1. Get rid of the parallel controllers (unless I misunderstood something and all these 5 requests really need to be executed at the same time)
2. Get rid of these `User1`, `User2`, etc and instead [parameterize your test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each JMeter thread (virtual user) would get its own credentials from the CSV file
3. Define the required amount of threads (virtual users) and loops (or test duration) on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

   [image]

   this way JMeter will start 5 threads (virtual users) in parallel and they will be executing Samplers for 100 iterations or 300 seconds